# RTCPeerConnection "undefined" in FireFox 62.0, 46.0, 47.0 etc

Tags: firefox, webrtc

It is supposed to be supported in FireFox, I have the webRTC adapter installed. It works fine in chrome. But in Firefox I get"undefined" for these:

```
console.log(window.RTCPeerConnection);
console.log(window.mozRTCPeerConnection);
```

I find it very strange,  I've tried multiple versions of Firefox, and it is almost as if it is not supported at all.

In the Firefox inspector this is the error I get:

```
TypeError: RTCPeerConnection is not a constructor
```

Answer (score 2):

WebRTC can be disabled in Firefox by a profile setting and there are extensions which disable it. Check if that is the case by searching for media.peerconnection.enabled in about:config